# Ninject: call a method with each Get call

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, ninject

I have a **Singleton Binding** on Ninject and I would like to call a method whenever DI resolves it (i.e. with each Get call). Ninject has OnActivation method that is called when the object is resolved only.

I am aware that using Transient scope will be the intuitive solution but due to out-of-control reason. The object must be singleton.

Comment: This doesn't seem like something that a DI framework would support. You might have better luck looking into something like [Castle DynamicProxy](https://github.com/castleproject/Core/blob/master/docs/dynamicproxy-introduction.md) that allows you to intercept calls to class/interface members

Comment: @devNull This is actually something that some DI libraries *do* support. But I don't know whether Ninject contains such feature. Although there are good reasons for such feature, it would be good if OP could tell us *why* he needs this as there might be other (or more effective) solutions to his problem.

Comment: I have never used Ninject, but the DI implementation of ASP.NET core supports setting definig a factory method that gets called when resolving your service. `    services.AddScoped(serviceProvider => { return new ResolveMe(); });`. Maybe there is something similar in Ninject?

Comment: @Steven, I need it to reset the properties of the singleton before each usage.

Comment: @Mostafaabdo: In that case I suggest you take a step back and reevaluate your design. Making changes to a singleton every time it is resolved is typically not a good idea. I suggest you update your question and describe what it is you are trying to achieve and explain _why_ you need this: show the singleton, show its usage, and explain why it needs to be 'reset'. We might be able to supply you with feedback on how to improve the design.

Comment: @Steven, I agree that is not the best design. However, as I mentioned in the question: due to out-of-control reason, I must use a singleton rather than transient scope. I was hoping that Ninject has a custom resolver method, but apparently it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with some trickery.
Let me give you an example:

```
const string Name = "Foo";

// Singleton Binding. Will only be used when the context uses the {Name}
Bind<Foo>().To<Foo>()
    .Named(Name)
    .InSingletonScope();

// Unnamed binding with method call on each resolution
Bind<Foo>().ToMethod(ctx => 
    {
        // Do anything arbitrary here. like calling a method...
        return ctx.Kernel.Get<Foo>(Name));
    });
```

When `Foo` (unnamed) is requested from the kernel it will resolve to the `ToMethod` binding - where you can insert any arbitrary code you like. In the end, the method must use the kernel to request `Foo`, but this time with a name-condition. This will resolve to the named singleton binding.